# How to extend EF6 class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am not sure why my EF class isn't extended.
Everything resides in the same project and I verified that the namespaces are the same.

I thought that this was the correct way to extend an EF class, but when I access MY_CLASS I do not see my extended fields.

How can I extend an EF6 class?

I have the following class from EF6

```
namespace MyProject.DataAccess
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

       public partial class MY_CLASS
        {
            public int AAA { get; set; }
            public byte BBB { get; set; }
            public int CCC { get; set; }
        }
}
```

I then created a file called PartialClasses.cs

```
namespace MyProject.DataAccess
{
    public partial class Entities : DbContext
    {
        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            // Code to save...
        }
    }

    [MetadataType(typeof(mdMyClass))]
    public partial class MY_CLASS { }
}
```

I then have a class mdMyClass:

```
namespace MyProject.DataAccess
{
    partial class mdDocTrackMap
    {
        public int AAA { get; set; }
        public byte BBB { get; set; }
        public int CCC { get; set; }

        // Extended Fields....
        public string DDD { get; set; }
        public string EEE { get; set; }
        public string FFF { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your partial is empty so it won't add any properties. Also `MetadataType` classes are only useful for adding meta data to existing properties, they can't add new ones. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to take the class generated  from EF and add 3 fields to them.  I don't need to store these fields in the database since they already are stored in the DB.  I know I can create a new object and map everything into it.  I was curious if just extending an EF class was an easier way to accomplish this.

Comment: You can extend them, you just need to add the properties into the partial class, not the metadata class.

Comment: Then doesn't that get wiped out on a refresh from the DB?

Comment: Why would it get wiped out? It's a partial class, that basically means you are splitting the class definition across multiple files, nothing more.